# Make HTML table to display data types of the variables in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

[image]I am new to PHP and I was stuck with this question. I have to create HTML table to display data types variables and this is what I came with so far. I can't understand how to put the values in the columns of the tables. I have attached the question image and below is my code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>

table
{
border-style:solid;

border-width:2px;

border-color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#EEFDEF">
<?php

$vStatus="true";
$vAge=25;
$vSalary=27733.5;
$Name="Stewart Laura";

if(is_scalar($vStatus) and is_scalar($vAge) and is_scalar($vSalary) and is_scalar($Name)){

}

if(is_int($vStatus) and is_scalar($vAge) and is_scalar($vSalary) and is_scalar($Name)){

}
if(is_float($vStatus) and is_scalar($vAge) and is_scalar($vSalary) and is_scalar($Name)){

}
if(is_bool($vStatus) and is_scalar($vAge) and is_scalar($vSalary) and is_scalar($Name)){

}
if(is_string($vStatus) and is_scalar($vAge) and is_scalar($vSalary) and is_scalar($Name)){

}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Variable</th>
<th>Scalar</th>
<th>Int</th>
<th>Float</th>
<th>Boolean</th>
<th>String</th>
</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try a Google search for `php and html example`, you should come up with more than plenty examples and tutorials that can teach you how to mix php with html.

Comment: Some nice examples to start with https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php

Comment: the exercise is for you. wouldn't it feel more gratifying if you were able to overcome this. by the way, `$vStatus` value isn't quoted, it's a boolean, not a quoted string true.

Comment: `echo is_scalar($vAge);` outputs `1` so your table data contents shouldn't need a bunch of _if_ tests, just something like `<td><?php echo is_scalar($vAge); ?></td>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is homework question so the following answer is uncommented and untested. I'll leave you to figure it out.

```
$vStatus=true;
$vAge=25;
$vSalary=27733.5;
$Name="Stewart Laura";

$tbl = "<table><thead><tr><th>Variable</th><th>Scalar</th><th>Int</th><th>Float</th></th>Boolean</th><th>String</th></tr></thead><th><tbody>";

tbl .= "<tr><th>$vStatus</th>".getDataType( $vStatus )."</tr>";
tbl .= "<tr><th>$vAge</th>".getDataType( $vAge )."</tr>";
tbl .= "<tr><th>$vSalary</th>".getDataType( $vSalary )."</tr>";
tbl .= "<tr><th>$Name</th>".getDataType( $Name )."</tr>";
tbl .= "</tbody></table>";

function getDataType( $type ) {
    $result = [];
    $result = array_fill(0, 5, '&nbsp');
    
    if( is_scalar( $type ) ) $result[0] = 'yes';
    if( is_int(    $type ) ) $result[1] = 'yes';
    if( is_float(  $type ) ) $result[2] = 'yes';
    if( is_bool(   $type ) ) $result[3] = 'yes';
    if( is_string( $type ) ) $result[4] = 'yes';
    
    $tmp = implode( $result, "</td><td>" );
    
    $result = "<td>".$tmp."</td>";
    
    return $result;
}
```